# Find the value of $A$, $n$ and $b$ if $y=A\sin(nt)+b$ has range $[2,8]$ and period $\frac{2\pi}{3}$.

Tags: trigonometry

> A function with rule $y=A\sin(nt)+b$ has range $[2,8]$ and period $\frac{2\pi}{3}$. Find the value of $A$, $n$ and $b$.

According to the teacher tip

> - Do Dilations before translations

But found translations first and I got $n$ , it is right?

> $\frac{2\pi}{3}n$=$2\pi$ 
>   $n=3$

But I don't know how to find $A$ and $b$.
 Many thanks.

Comment: You know that $-1 \leq \sin\,x \leq 1$, no? What happens if you multiply by $A$ all sides of that inequality?

Comment: sorry, no. I'm confuse. thx

Comment: You don't need to think about translations since that's already given when it says that it's of the form $y=A\sin(nt)+b$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We know that $\sin(x)$ takes values in the range $[-1, 1]$. When $\sin(nt)$ attains its maximum of $1$, we want $y$ to be $8$. Plug the values into the equation to get:

$$
8 = A + b
$$

Similarly, when $\sin(nt)$ is $-1$, we want $y$ to be $2$:

$$
2 = -A + b
$$

Now, you have a system of 2 equations with 2 variables. Solve to get $A$ and $b$.

Answer (score 3):

We know that:

$$ -1 \leq \sin (3t) \leq 1$$

Multiplying both sides by $A$:

$$ -A \leq A\sin (3t) \leq +A$$

Then by adding $b$ to both sides, we have:

$$ -A+b \leq A\sin (3t)+b \leq A+b \tag{1}$$

Comparing $(1)$ to what you have from the question that $ 2 \leq y \leq 8$, you can easily find the values of $A$ and $b$ from the system of equations:

$$
 \left\{
    \begin{array}{ll}
        -A+b=2 &  \\
        A+b=8 & 
    \end{array}
\right.
$$